# marking duplicate in a new column in R

Tags: r

The following example, 
is (an extreme exemplification) of my data.

```
structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("aaa", "bbb", "burp"), class = "factor")), .Names = "X", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")

dataExample
     X
1  aaa
2 burp
3  bbb
4  aaa
5 burp
6 burp
7  bbb
8  aaa
```

EDIT: Based on the content of one column (e.g., 'X'), I would like to create a new column (e.g., 'desired') which tells me, for each 'character code' in the 'X' column, whether I am looking at the first , the second, or at the nth occurrence of the code. In addition, there one specific 'code' from 'X', which needs to be excluded from this counting process, and represented as it is (e.g., 'burp').

Here it is an example of the expected outcome

```
    X     desired
1  aaa       1
2 burp      burp
3  bbb       1
4  aaa       2
5 burp      burp
6 burp      burp
7  bbb       2
8  aaa       3
```

NB: the column 'desired' represents the expected outcome, it is not part of the data set.

Comment: That's it?  Where's the rest of the question?

Comment: Are you sure you want mixed classes in your desired output? I.e., what class should be the numbers?

Comment: @RichardScriven That's it. In the real world data set I only have thousands rows, and hundreds data.frames, and 40 unique strings in a non trivial format, with one to leave untouched, as above.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I will be fine with 'character' representation for everything

Comment: I meant that you give no explanation of what the new column consists of.

Comment: @RichardScriven, I hope that the edited version clarifies my request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some possible solutions:

With Base R

```
df$desired <- with(df, ave(as.character(X), X, FUN = function(x) seq_len(length(x))))
df[df$X == "burp", "desired"] <- "burp"
```

Or With `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, desired := as.character(seq_len(.N)), 
                                 X][X == "burp", desired := "burp"]
```

Or with `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
  group_by(X) %>%
  mutate(desired = ifelse(X == "burp", "burp", as.character(row_number())))
```

---

**Edit:** Per Op's comment, here's an illustration that all the approaches work

```
df$desiredBase <- with(df, ave(as.character(X), X, FUN = function(x) seq_len(length(x))))
df[df$X == "burp", "desiredBase"] <- "burp"

setDT(df)[, desiredDT := as.character(seq_len(.N)), 
          X][X == "burp", desiredDT := "burp"]

setDF(df) %>%
  group_by(X) %>%
  mutate(desiredplyr = ifelse(X == "burp", "burp", as.character(row_number())))

# Source: local data frame [8 x 4]
# Groups: X
# 
#      X desiredBase desiredDT desiredplyr
# 1  aaa           1         1           1
# 2 burp        burp      burp        burp
# 3  bbb           1         1           1
# 4  aaa           2         2           2
# 5 burp        burp      burp        burp
# 6 burp        burp      burp        burp
# 7  bbb           2         2           2
# 8  aaa           3         3           3
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L
      ), .Label = c("aaa", "bbb", "burp"), class = "factor")), .Names = "X", row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Dear David, your answers were helpful, however, the `dplyr` implementation does not work well with `ifelse`, in fact `row_number()` remains with no argument, generating an `Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default`. So, for now, I kept your `dplyr` solution, without `ifelse`, to generate the new column, and then I perform the substitution `df$desired[df$X == 'burp']  <- 'burp'`. p.s. The `data.table` option also contains an error.

Comment: What error are you getting for `data.table` solution? Also, the `dplyr` solution doesn't work because you are running it after you've ran the `data.table` version. Try running the `dplyr` solution on a new R session *before* running the `data.table` solution.

Comment: I've added the results for all the approaches combined *and* your data set. Everything seem to work just fine

Comment: The `dplyr` only works in your example because your are running it on `df <- structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L
      ), .Label = c("aaa", "bbb", "burp"), class = "factor"), desired = structure(c(1L, 
      4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "burp"
      ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X", "desired"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
      "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))`, which is the pre-edited version of the data. NB: I am running it in a new R session in which `data.table` has not even been loaded.

Comment: Ok, I've rerun on the new data set and it works perfectly fine. Maybe you have old `dplyr`  version? Please reinstall to a newer one

Comment: The `data.table` version works great!

Comment: I moved from v 0.2 to 0.4.1 of `dplyr` now it works greats. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your limited input:

```
df <- structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("aaa", "bbb", "burp"), class = "factor"), desired = structure(c(1L,4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "burp"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X", "desired"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

desired <- numeric(nrow(df))
set <- df$X
for(k in seq_along(set)){
  cur_set <- set[1:k]
  cur_el <- set[k]
  tbl <- table(cur_set)
  desired[k] <- ifelse(cur_el == "burp", "burp", tbl[names(tbl) == cur_el])
}

df$desired_new <- desired
> df
     X desired desired_new
1  aaa       1           1
2 burp    burp        burp
3  bbb       1           1
4  aaa       2           2
5 burp    burp        burp
6 burp    burp        burp
7  bbb       2           2
8  aaa       3           3
```